# How to return to the beginning of a DictReader?

Tags: python

If I call the `company_at_node` method (shown below) twice, it will only print a row for the first call. I thought maybe that I needed to `seek` back to the beginning of the reader for the next call, so I added
       `self.companies.seek(0)`
to the end of the `company_at_node` method but DictReader has no attribute seek. Since the file is never closed (and since I didn't get an error message to that effect), I didn't think this was a `ValueError i/o operation on closed file` (which there are numerous questions about on SO)

Is there a way to return to the beginning of a DictReader to iterate through a second time (i.e. a second function call)?

```
class CSVReader:
    def __init__(self):
        f = open('myfile.csv')
        self.companies = csv.DictReader(f)


    def company_at_node(self, node):
        for row in self.companies:
            if row['nodeid'] == node:
                print row
        self.companies.seek(0)
```

Comment: You have to `f.seek()` and re-initialize `DictReader` but it is better to load the whole dict into memory if it not huge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do f.seek(0) instead of DictReader. Then, you can modify your code to be able to access file. This should work:

```
class CSVReader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = open('myfile.csv')
        self.companies = csv.DictReader(f)


    def company_at_node(self, node):
        for row in self.companies:
            if row['nodeid'] == node:
                print row
        self.f.seek(0)
```

Comment: in terms of efficiency, do you think that's a better solution than doing `rows = list(reader)`

Comment: You are't creating memory overhead by using f.seek but creating list is really bad idea if you have big file.

Comment: That trick didn't work in `3.7.4`, needs the `csv.DictReader` recreation.

Comment: My original code used `data=csv.DictReader(open(csvfile, 'r'), delimiter=",")` and I realized that I had to break out the `open(csvfile, 'r')` component into its own variable in order to be able to reset the index. This answer helped me realize that - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In `reader = csv.DictReader(f)` the instance `reader` is an iterator. An iterator emits a unit of data on each explicit/ implicit invocation of  `__next__` on it. Now that process is called *consuming* the iterator, which can happen only once. This is how the iterator construct provides the ultimate memory efficiency. So if you want random indexing make a sequence out of it like,

```
rows = list(reader)
```

Comment: I voted you up fro being helpful (someone had voted you down). I'm curious whether your solution or the other one (calling seek on the file) is more efficent

Comment: @Leahcim Thanks for the upvote. as the question concerned with making the code work rather than optimizing a working snippet. I gave a solution that works. Given the requirements I should be downvoted *if my solution doesn't work* and downvoting for efficiency reasons, in my opinion, is presuming your opponent naive or stupid. Whoever it was I challenge that person for a duel :)