# Can't read from file 'a+'

Tags: python, csv

I have a class named Database, which opens a file in 'a+' mode(for reading and appending). Also it has methods for appending and reading from file using csv library as follows:

```
class Database():
    def __init__(self, db_filename, *args, **kwargs):
        self._db_file = open(db_filename, 'a+', newline='')
        self._csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
            self._db_file, fieldnames=self.__FIELDNAMES)
        self._csv_reader = csv.DictReader(
            self._db_file, fieldnames=self.__FIELDNAMES)
    # append
    def save(self, data):
        self._csv_writer.writerow(data)
    # read
    def load(self):
        data = []
        for row in self._csv_reader
            data.append(row)
        return data
```

The problem is that `save` method works fine, but `load` doesn't. *self._csv_reader* is empty.

Comment: Tried flush() and os.fsync(fd), won't work

Comment: Opening with `a` positions you at the end of the file, so there's nothing to read. Open it in `r` mode.

Comment: Or you can file seek to start before reading https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a file with `a+` mode, the file stream will be positioned at the end of the file. Call `f.seek( 0 )` where f is a file object created with `open( ... )` before you create your `DictReader`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257774/how-to-return-to-the-beginning-of-a-dictreader) for a more detailed discussion about this issue.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! In addition, after using save() and then load(), it reads previous data, that was stored before save(). I added fd.seek(0) ins load again and it did the job. Is there another solution?

Comment: @МаксимКолодников When you create the document, you can store the current seek position with `f.tell()`. This will be the position in the file after all current data and before any future data. Once you save the data, you could seek to that position so that any future reads would only access new data.