# Python why file with content cannot be read?

Tags: python, file

```
import pathlib    
file_name = '%s/survey_ids.txt' % pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
        
f = open(file_name, "a+")
f.write("hello world\n")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

The first time I run the script, it creates the file `survey_ids.txt` and writes `hello world\n` to it. It doesn't print anything for sure. But for the second time I run it, it writes another `hello world\n` to `survey_ids.txt` but doesn't print anything still. I suppose it will print `hello world\n`. Why would this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't read from file 'a+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422921/cant-read-from-file-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f.write` advances the stream position. So when you read the file using `f.read()` it will try to read from current stream position to the end of the file.
To get the expected behavior try to `seek` to byte offset 0 before the `.read` call.

```
f = open("test.txt", "a+")
f.write("hello world\n")
f.seek(0)
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Also as recommended within the comments it's better [to use context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) which will clean up the resources automatically.

Comment: Very clear answer.  Perhaps improve by recommending the use of a context manager, instead of the current structure.

Comment: Could you suggest `with` context manager solution ?

Comment: @arzo you can refer 2nd solution for that

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file with `a+` mode, the file stream will be positioned at the end of the file. Call `f.seek( 0 )` where f is a file object created with `open( ... )` before you create your DictReader. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257774/how-to-return-to-the-beginning-of-a-dictreader) for a more detailed discussion about this issue.

```
f = open("test.txt", "a+")
f.write("hello world\n")
f.seek(0)
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

and for with open

```
with open(file_name, "a+") as f:
    f.write("hello world\n")
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```